# Adding instruction label on UIpickerviewcontroller editing view

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, label

I've seen in the Facebook app the ability to have instructions on the image edit view when selecting a picture, on the bottom of their(fb) view it says, "use two fingers to draw crop area", i want to add that to my crop instructions but can't find it.

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook app probaby achieves this using the Camera Overlay API's.

Take a look at his blog post for info on using the camera overlay API: http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/10/custom-video-overlay-view-on-the-iphone/